# DB design for a web app

Tags: database, playframework

I'm doing a webapp that uses REST api to retrieve information from a ticketing service, builds its own schema and presents the data as statistics.

Every time a user connects to my webapp I need to populate four tables and every time he logs out I need to delete the content.

Ideally I need a db for each user.

How should I do this?

Comment: Why do you need a database for each user?

Comment: @MMM: isolation and all that stuff. But this setup/teardown cycle worries me :-)

Answer (score 2):

check the [multi-db](http://www.playframework.org/modules/multidb-1.0/home) module and [play support for multiple db](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/model#multiple).